# Update listbox of form2 from form1 withouting creating form2 again

Tags: vb.net

I have a project that passes data from Form1 to Form2, Form1 will be show in monitor1 and Form2 in monitor2. I'm achieving this result but it creates another instance of Form2 every time I want to update the data in Form2. Is there a way to update Form2 without creating a new one?

```
        Dim OBJ As New Form2
        OBJ.ListBox1.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items)
        OBJ.ListBox2.Items.AddRange(ListBox2.Items)
        OBJ.Label1.Text = TextBox3.Text
        OBJ.Show()
    End Sub
```

I searched the internet but all I found is creating a new Form2 rather than updating the exisisting one.

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough, while I often tell beginners not to use default instances of forms and to create their own instances, this is one case where you could benefit from using a default instance.  The default instance is managed by the system so it will only create a new instance if one is required, i.e. no instance has yet been created or the last one created has been disposed.

```
Form2.ListBox1.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items)
Form2.ListBox2.Items.AddRange(ListBox2.Items)
Form2.Label1.Text = TextBox3.Text

'Display the instance if it is new and focus it otherwise.
Form2.Show()
Form2.Activate()
```

By using the class name there instead of a variable of that type, you are referring to the default instances.  Read more [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html).

The alternative is to manage a single instance yourself, which is what you'd need to do in C# or VB.NET before default instances.

```
Private f2 As Form2

Private Sub UpdateForm2()
    If f2 Is Nothing OrElse f2.IsDisposed Then
        f2 = New Form2
    End If

    f2.ListBox1.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items)
    f2.ListBox2.Items.AddRange(ListBox2.Items)
    f2.Label1.Text = TextBox3.Text

    'Display the instance if it is new and focus it otherwise.
    f2.Show()
    f2.Activate()
End Sub
```